# Was the AI in Angel Beats really the programmer?

Tags: angel-beats

I was looking up who might be the Programmer in Angel Beats and one name doesn't really appear anywhere...the AI. I've put a case together below and was wondering if I could get your thoughts and if you have anything that would assist or reject the idea the AI is actually the programmer.

Firstly it's important to ask, is the AI an NPC? Well there are differences, clearly the AI can think, understand the fundamentals of the world etc however, it's also in a human body, it has similar traits to NPCs.

1. We know the programmer went mad and eventually turned into an NPC as confirmed by the AI. If you consider the AI an NPC then it could be him.
2. The AI knows the programmer's name but said you won't know him, ruling out pretty much everyone she knows. Whilst you might argue he didn't say it's "Me" the AI confirmed he "Didn't know anything" meaning if he said his own name as the programmer he wouldn't recognise it to be himself since he's an AI.
3. The AI didn't create Angel Player, whilst the programmer might not have either it might suggest the AI was put in the world after it's creation. However the programmer didn't create it either, he amended it when he realised there was a bug in the software which is the only reason he was there to begin with.
4. The programmer was mad, he made some rules before turning into an NPC which the AI follows, who better than to appoint himself of this role and erase his memory so he can forget his love.

Some people might ask why the AI would be so open to letting someone else take over the world, well regardless of whoever the Programmer is, he clearly didn't specify a command not to allow this.

What do you think? Or have I missed something vital?

Comment: Perhaps related: [Who is the mysterious Programmer of Angel Beats?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/33601/2516)

Comment: Also, looks like you're asking the community whether to confirm/reject your theory. We have a guideline on [How do we respond to "Is my theory right?" questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4014/2516). So, you may consider [edit]ing the question to have enough context for the topic to be answerable, then posting the theory as an answer so that it can be evaluated independently from the question by the community. Thanks